# Is there a way to ailgn a MigLayout column to another JPanel's inner component?

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm trying to align the 'third' **column** to the 'browse' button inside the panel above (whose layout is also a MigLayout). Hadn't found any command to do it, then tried to align it manually (using the windowbuilder plugin for Eclipse), as displayed in the image below, but the final result just isn't the same as it looked in the windowbuilder editor (second image). Anyone knows why, or knows a command to solve this issue? Thanks

[windowbuilder screen image](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2731/z6u9.png)

[application image](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/9630/8j1c.png)

**EDIT:**
Solved the manual alignment by deleting the first two columns (column 0 and 1.. it seems since they didnt have a preferred width they were causing some interference - don't know how exactly - on the following columns)
Though I'd really prefer to do that by using an expression/command of some kind to align a columns with the 'x' position of a component, as I said before .. =. If anyone knows of a better solution I'd really like to know =]

Thanks!

Comment: hmm .. why do you have two panels? Mig works best with an all-in-one approach. BTW: the border is visual clutter anyway (but might be a requirement :-), as explained in some articles by JGoodies

Comment: started reading about JGoodies, and liked the idea of using separators instead of border, thanks =]. But anyway, I'd like to know if there's any way to solve this kind of problem with nested panels, for future reference, in case I still see myself in need of doing it (perhaps a requirement, as you mentioned) =z